# Xcodeから直接端末に入れたアプリとAppStoreからダウンロードしたアプリで違いはありますか？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

Swiftであるアプリを開発し、リリースしているのですが、AppStoreからダウンロードしたアプリの一部端末でUILabel(文字)が一切表示されない場合があり、私が所持しているiPhoneXS Maxでも文字が表示されなくなりました。

しかし、全く同じプログラム(証明書のみが異なる)で、Xcodeから直接同じiPhoneXS Maxに入れてみたところ問題なくUILabel(文字)が表示されました。

他の端末(iPad/iPhone XRなど)でAppStore経由でダウンロードしたユーザーの一部で実験したところ、やはりXcodeから直接入れた場合や、Bitrise→Fabricでのテスト配布で入れた場合は文字が表示されました。

まとめると
①Xcodeから入れた場合問題なくラベルの文字が表示がされるアプリが、全く同じプログラムにも関わらずAppStore経由だと表示されない
②iPhone XS系/iPhoneXR系/iPadの一部端末で、全く文字が表示されない状態を確認。iPhone SEのみ一部、表示される文字と表示されない文字がまばらにある状態で確認。
③Xcode経由、Fabricでのテスト配布経由は問題なし。AppStore経由のみ問題あり。

AppStore経由のものだけ、なにか(特にレイアウトやUI系について)別の処理がされることはあるのでしょうか？

また、AppStore上のアプリのUIデバッグをうまくする方法があればご教示ください。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 私にはそのような経験はありません。AppStoreで公開中のアプリと全く同じバージョンのXcodeを使ってビルドしていますか？TestFlightでインストールした場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: 私にもそのような経験はありません。App Store上のアプリのUIデバッグをするには、TestFlight を使うのがベストだと思います。App Storeで配信されるものと同じものを公開前にインストールできるはずなので

Comment: @TatsuhiroSAWA 
コメントありがとうございます。証明書以外のプログラムはすべて同じで、バージョン番号(ビルド番号)のみXcodeプロジェクト上とAppStoreConnectで違います。

TestFlightは使っておりませんが、FabricやDeployGateは使って配布しており、問題なく文字は表示されております。

Comment: @小川航佑 コメントありがとうございます。TestFlightで試してみようと思います。

Comment: コメント失礼します。
私も同様の問題で悩まされております。
どのように解決されたのかご教示頂けませんでしょうか。